# How to redirect query string using spring boot

Tags: java, spring

i want open redirect  vulnerabilities code using spring boot

a request which takes query string and redirect to the another page

```
@GetMapping("/vpn/gas/{web}")
@ResponseBody
public RedirectView getFoo(@RequestParam String a,@RequestParam String b,@PathVariable ("web") String web) {
     String url =  web + ".com";
   RedirectView rv = new RedirectView();
         
    rv.setUrl(web);
  
    return rv;
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Please read [ask]. Then come back and edit your question.

Comment: It seems to be better to use an anchor HTML element instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
@GetMapping("/vpn/gas/{web}")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getFoo(@RequestParam String a,@RequestParam String b,@PathVariable ("web") String web) {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

     String url =  web + ".com";
   RedirectView rv = new RedirectView();
         
    rv.setUrl(web);
  
    mv.setView(rv);

    return mv;
}
```